# How to redirect Android app stdout/stderr with ADB?

Tags: android, emulator

I want to automate more of the software development process for some Android command line applications. Years ago, I would have installed Busybox on a physical Android device, fetched a microscope, and started typing in Emacs for Android. Today, I am looking for a more convenient way to code.

In particular, I want to redirect the stdout and stderr file descriptors for Android (NDK) applications, similar to how qemu-arm64-static works.

Does anyone know if this is possible with ADB? As an alternative, I could structure my applications as microservices and use ADB port forwarding. But I'd lose a lot of classic UNIX conventions in doing so.

I see that ADB has logging capture, for NDK (log.h) and SDK (Log.class) messages. But sadly, I am not seeing a clear way to redirect host STDIN to Android guest application STDIN.

Maybe there is a way to trigger Toybox (mksh) via adb and send custom sh commands there?

Answer (score 0):

Various sources (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36561699/340175 and https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/671#issuecomment-383890481) recommend the approach described in https://codelab.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/how-to-use-standard-output-streams-for-logging-in-android-apps/

For posterity the code in that blog post follows:

```
static int pfd[2];
static pthread_t thr;
static const char *tag = "myapp";

int start_logger(const char *app_name)
{
    tag = app_name;

    /* make stdout line-buffered and stderr unbuffered */
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    /* create the pipe and redirect stdout and stderr */
    pipe(pfd);
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    dup2(pfd[1], 2);

    /* spawn the logging thread */
    if(pthread_create(&thr, 0, thread_func, 0) == -1)
        return -1;
    pthread_detach(thr);
    return 0;
}

static void *thread_func(void*)
{
    ssize_t rdsz;
    char buf[128];
    while((rdsz = read(pfd[0], buf, sizeof buf - 1)) > 0) {
        if(buf[rdsz - 1] == '\n') --rdsz;
        buf[rdsz] = 0;  /* add null-terminator */
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, tag, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This involves writing and/or modifying code.

There is a dated approach that may still work for some emulators of older versions of Android (I've not tried it out) which is discussed in a sibling article on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531050/redirect-stdout-to-logcat-in-android-ndk I don't think it's sensible to try and reproduce the discussion from that Q&A here, particularly as the choices depend on various factors discussed in that topic. Please do update this topic once you've made progress.